# How to use django tree-menu

Tags: django-templates

I try to use django-treemenus.
http://code.google.com/p/django-treemenus/

I create a tree menu (and menu item) using the admin interface.
When I try to load menus using show_meny tag ( below you find my template where I call this tag).

I think I need to call   treemenus/menu.html ( given in the sample to start) , but I don't know how? shoold I modify my TEMPLATE_DIRS ?

```
{% extends "polls/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Poll list{% endblock %}
{# we override the block content here#}
{% block content %}

**{% load tree_menu_tags %}
{% show_menu "home" "vertical" %}**


    {% if object_list %}
        <ul>
            {% for poll in object_list %}
            <li>{{ poll.question }} at [ {{poll.pub_date|date:"F j, Y"}}]</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No polls are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found your question while looking for the answer to a different treemenu question and I think I'm (just barely) qualified to answer.

The answer is no, you don't need to modify your TEMPLATE_DIRS.  You do need to create a treemenus directory inside your template directory and inside that put a menu.html and menu_item.html.   You will find examples of both of those in the docs directory of the django-treemenus distribution.